# How can I split string to several folders?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, path

I have a case like this:

```
Path = 'C:\Intel\ExtremeGraphics\CUI\Resource'
```

I want to split this string to list with the string folders names:

```
['C:', 'Intel', 'ExtremeGraphics', 'CUI, 'Resource']
```

How can I do that in the shortest way?

Answer (score 0):

folders = Path.split('\')

It will return you the required list of the folders